# Vue many erros on Chrome console from vue.runtime.esm.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm having a lot o f errors from the `vue.runtime.esm.js` file on debug console.
I'm developing an application with Vuetify Framework and I wonder how can I discover where those errors come from.

[image]

Comment: does your terminal/shell show any errors? Can you provide at least a few of the errors?